Can individual topological space be considered as category?
Of course, I am aware of Top (category of topological spaces). My question is about something different - can any topological space be considered as category? E.g. its objects may be the open sets of the category and the morphisms - some or all of its mapping? Or maybe different assignments can be made?
I think that it may be possible, but I have never seen any article that exploits such fact? Maybe this fact is pretty trivial and so worthless that noone mentions and uses it? I have found only 2 articles with phrase "space as category": http://www.numdam.org/article/CTGDC_1976__17_3_295_0.pdf but they are not providing any more insights https://www.hindawi.com/journals/amp/2011/957592/
I am thinking about embedding theories (FOL, HOL, type theories - as categories of contexts) into spaces and such embedding can be formulated as functors. Of course, not all such embeddings exist, but maybe I can invent something about approximation. Such setting would be categorial approach to knowledge graph embeddings or graph embeddings more generally - using category theory.
Note added. The suggestion about presheaf is very encouraging, especially because there is already work 'Knowledge Sheaves: A Sheaf-Theoretic Framework for Knowledge Graph Embedding' https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.03789 with such naming. But I am still reading about this - because presheaf is assignment of some new sets to the open sets of the space, but I would like to stay in the space.

You could define a category whose objects are points in the space, and morphisms are continuous curves joining the points, possibly up to path-homotopy. I guess that amounts to the fundamental groupoid.

There are many ways to assign a category to a topological space: besides the one you mentioned (the full subcategory of Top consisting of the opens of X) you can take the specialization preorder, the poset of opens, the funtamental groupoid, the category of sheaves, etc. I suspect your question really is not "can you view a space as a category" but rather you really want to ask about something very very specific but you don't know how to formulate it. I suggest you try to focus your question more.

FYI: presheaf

There is a notion closely related to the notion of topological space, and that is the notion of locale: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locale, a specific type of poset and hence of category (namely a complete lattice for which finite meets distribute over arbitrary joins). The topology of a topological space, i.e. the set of open subsets ordered by inclusion, forms a locale. A wide class of spaces, namely sober spaces, have the property that their points can be retrieved from the topology as locale. If this is of interest, it can be developed into an answer.

@user43208 many thxs for this already. I am still confused and learning.

As people in the comments have noted, there are many ways to view a topological space $X$ as a category. One obvious way is to look at its poset of open sets $\mathcal{O} X$, viewed as a category. This certainly remembers lots about $X$, and in case $X$ is sober this poset (read: category) actually remembers everything about $X$. Moreover, in this setting one can show that functors $\mathcal{O}Y \to \mathcal{O}X$ that preserve finite limits and arbitrary colimits (read: finite intersections and all unions) are exactly the same thing as continuous maps $X \to Y$.
A more intricate version of the same story is to look at the topos of sheaves on $X$, $\mathsf{Sh}(X)$. This is a more complicated category than just the poset of open sets, but is still very concrete to work with. Again, provided $X$ is sober the assignment $X \mapsto \mathsf{Sh}(X)$ is a fully faithful embedding (and again, a continuous function $X \to Y$ is the same thing as a functor $\mathsf{Sh}(Y) \to \mathsf{Sh}(X)$ preserving finite limits and all colimits). For this reason topoi are often called "generalized spaces", and this is probably the most compelling 1-categorical way to view a topological space as a category (if you identify $X$ with $\mathsf{Sh}(X)$, as many working topos theorists do).
However, if you're willing to work with $\infty$-categories, then there's another compelling way to view $X$ as an ($\infty$-)category. We basically define an "$\infty$-groupoid" (that is, an $\infty$-category where all maps are invertible) to be a space. In particular, every topological space naturally gives us an $\infty$-groupoid, which is a version of the fundamental groupoid that remembers all the homotopy structure of $X$ (rather than just the $1$-dimensional structure, which is all the fundamental groupoid sees). Much as a topos theorist would say that $\mathsf{Sh}(X)$ is $X$, so too would an $\infty$-category theorist say that this $\infty$-groupoid is $X$ (up to homotopy). In particular, there are many interesting ($\infty$-)categorical constructions one can study, which in the special case of $X$ give interesting topological information about $X$. I wrote a lot more about the back and forth between spaces and $\infty$-groupoids here if you're interested in reading more.

I hope this helps ^_^

Nice answer. But the last paragraph should be modified -- no? -- to say that you can use $\infty$-groupoids to remember everything about a topological space up to homotopy equivalence, or weak homotopy equivalence. (How much of this discussion will be clear to the OP is hard to say.)

I appreciate answer very much and the infinity-groupid insight especially, because by embedding type theories I had embedding HoTT theories in my mind. I am reading that HoTT has topos, infinity-categorical and groupoid semantics, but I am thinking about embedding in Euclidean spaces because this is how the neural networks functions. I know that not all the simplices (e.g. as nerves of the category of contect for concrete HoTT theory) are Euclidean embeddable, but then one can invent some approximate embeddings. The goal is to research how theories are embedded and function in neural networks.

Even more, I guess, we can go beyond sheafs (functor into Set) to stacks (functor into Cat) and consider topos of stacks? https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.14587 "Topos and stacks of deep Neural Networks" is one preliminary effort in this direction, although the preprint seems to be a bit vauge and still in the peer-review and revision state.

@user43208 -- great point, haha. For a second there I forgot that there was anything other than a homotopy type, even though I was talking about it earlier in the answer. I'll make that change now!

Since I'm nitpicky, I would say "weak homotopy equivalence" (which sounds more technical, but whaddya gonna do?). For example, the map $p: [0, 1] \to S$ to Sierpinski space that sends $t > 0$ to $\top$ and $0$ to $\bot$ is a weak homotopy equivalence, but there are no continuous maps $S \to [0, 1]$ except for constant maps, so technically $p$ is not a homotopy equivalence.

Ah, I'm not that nitpicky :P
